# How do I find what ?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle points to?

Tags: android, android-theme

I have

```
android:button="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
```

on the layout for a CheckBox. I pressed F3 to take me to the definition, and it just said

```
    <!-- Drawable to use for single choice indicators. -->
    <attr name="listChoiceIndicatorSingle" format="reference" />
```

in `android-sdk/platforms/android-17/data/res/values/attrs.xml`. I searched the whole file and that was the only occurrence.

How do I find the drawables that it references?

Comment: What  you want to do? Im not getting your question. You want  to set a image to your button?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The value of attributes are defined in theme.xml. Check 'theme.xml' in SDK.
In my case, it defined like this:

```
<item name="listChoiceIndicatorSingle">@android:drawable/btn_radio_holo_dark</item>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to find the actual PNG drawables and copy them to my app, using a different color.